# How to fetch the Google Analytics Reporting API using Laravel 5?

Tags: php, google-analytics, laravel-5

I am trying hard for getting this with failing output since 2 days.
I am  using the Laravel 5 and trying to get the Google Analytics data,
I tried to install few packages like:

`ipunkt/laravel-analytics`  -> it gave me the render output.
but I want Analytics Data like `ga:organicSearches, ga:pageLoadTime, ...`

I also tried for other packages like
`timgws/Google-Analytics-API-PHP` -> but no expected output.
just gave the authenticated url with resulting `ErrorException`

How to get this data in laravel? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code you are having trouble with?

Comment: this is the link i followed https://github.com/ipunkt/laravel-analytics , I got the script provided by the Google Analytics. but rest of things are not coming